# SQL server 2008: can't save/change table design not error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have visual studio 2012 and sql server express 2008 I'm trying to make changes to an existing table in "Open Table Definition" column "Data type". I changed column "Data type" and I  close the window "Open Table Definition" . But nothing happens.No errors.When i used Visual Studio 2010-appeared "save widow"How to save in Visual Studio 2012 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

```
Tools->Options->Designers->Table and Database Designers
```

Uncheck the  'Prevent Saving Changes that required table re-Creation'

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to modify the table at the SQL Server Management Studio?

Anyway, if you modify anything on VS, it have to be saved first. If you can't find the save options, the keys Ctrl+S will help you.